# What is the purpose of using function `String()` with function argument?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently reading `'Singe Page Web Applications'` book. I encountered the following example:

```
// This is single pass encoder for html entities and handles
// an arbitrary number of characters
encodeHtml = function ( input_arg_str, exclude_amp) {
    var input_str = String( input_arg_str), regex, lookup_map;

    ...

    return input_str.replace(regex, function ( match, name ){
        return lookup_map[ match ] || '';
    });
};
```

I wonder, what is the purpose of using function `String()` with argument `input_arg_str`. I know that by using `String()` function I can convert different object to string, but I never met with such a feature using `String()`.

I'm curious what you think about this and top thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@Amit Joki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23389729/497356) is correct, of course, but there are several ways you could convert an object to a string, why use `String(...)`?

I'd guess the main reason here is that it safely handle's `null` and `undefined` whereas `.toString` would obviously fail.

```
String(undefined) // "undefined"
String(null) // "null"
```

In short, it's a more defensive way to convert an object to a string than `.toString`. Here's a note about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String):

> It's possible to use `String` as a "safer" `toString` alternative, as
>   although it still normally calls the underlying `toString`, it also
>   works for null and undefined.

I *believe* you get the same results with string concatenation:

```
var input_str = '' + input_arg_str; // also handles `null` and `undefined`
```

Comment: +1: Good point on the handling of `null` and `undefined`, however, I think in *most* cases you probably need to handle `null` or `undefined` differently anyway. In the OP's code it seems a little silly to run a regex against the string `undefined`. You're probably better off just returning `null`, `undefined` or an empty string.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `String(input_arg_str)` is easier to read/maintain than `'' + input_arg_str`.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: I considered mentioning that, but the `'' + input_arg_str` is a common JS idiom from what I've seen. I think it comes down to personal preference

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I've ever found a reason to use it, but MDN does suggest there are some subtle differences between string literals and string objects (emphasis mine):

> Note that JavaScript distinguishes between String objects and primitive string values. (The same is true of Boolean and Numbers.)
>
> String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without using the new keyword) are primitive strings. JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects, so that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings. In contexts where a method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and call the method or perform the property lookup.
>
> String primitives and String objects also give different results when using eval. Primitives passed to eval are treated as source code; String objects are treated as all other objects are, by returning the object.
>
> For these reasons, code may break when it encounters String objects when it expects a primitive string instead, although generally **authors need not worry about the distinction.**

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

As others have said, in the context of the code you posted, it does ensure that whatever was passed as `input_arg_str` is converted to an actual string.